# Facebook Search API - List all users based on location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to list all users who specify a given location as their "current city" using the Graph API or some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [search](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for [Users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and add fields to query by like hometown or location. The user must have opened their privacy settings though to share location with search.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Marcus&type=user&access_token=

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So I see that I can construct the URL as such: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=the_name&type=user&location=the_location&access_token=, but is there a way to display *all* users who have that location without providing a name as the query?  Or do you have to search by at least partial name?

Comment: not sure, give it a shot and see if it fails? my guess is Facebook might limit that since there could be millions of a users in a location like Manhattan.

Comment: Have you actually managed to get the location filter to work?  In my tests it seems to be simply ignored.

Comment: Don't see a way to search by location, any ideas?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. It seems bizarre that you can search for people by location using the facebook website but you can't using the api. If you find a way to do it please post it.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible, even if the app is authorized.

Here are the fields you can search by (marked with *)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Comment: FQL will be deprecated soon though. So sad

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search for users who haven't authorized your app.  Currently the search?q=xxxx&type=user searches only on name (facebook used to allow email, but removed that when they found out bad people were using that search to do bad things).

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you see Facebook notification when you try to search but found nothing, it says:

> Looking for people or posts? Try entering a name, location, or different words.

You can add location to the query, like: `my_name my_location` --> `"Aminah Nuraini" Indonesia`

It will only work if the user allows people to see their location, though.