# How do I search Facebook for all users at a certain location using Graph-API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I have a project where I have to search Facebook for all people at a
certain location and then apply further filters to the data. My problem and question is:

**How do I get the initial data, using Graph API?**

I know that it is possible, using the search field in Facebook itself. Just typing "All people living in ???" returns a list of people.
I couldn't find such functionality in the Graph-API of Facebook. Here is what I tried:

I modified some parameters of the standard search request

- `search?type=user&center=52.946758,-1.172882&distance=1000`
- `search?type=user&center=Nottingham&distance=1000`

and here is what I got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "No node specified", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

---

Using a similar query with `location` instead of `center`

- `search?type=user&location=Nottingham&distance=1000`
- `search?type=user&location=52.946758,-1.172882&distance=1000`
- `search?type=user&q=&location=Nottingham`

and only got a confusing error that the location I wrote is wrong

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#160) Invalid coordinates.  Coordinates must contain at least latitude and longitude.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 160
  }
}
```

---

Then searching for a user with the coordinates as `query` parameter returned an empty result.

- `search?type=user&q=52.946758,-1.172882&distance=1000`

`{"data": []}`

---

Then I tried to search for a correct location to pass to the `location` parameter of the query

- `search?type=location&q=52.946758,-1.172882`

and I only got a deprecation error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) location search is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

---

I don't know how to get to this. If someone could tell me, how to get this information, it would help
me a lot, since I don't know what to try next.

I have found this question similar to my problem, but the accepted answer isn't really answering the question
[Facebook Search API - List all users based on location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054841/facebook-search-api-list-all-users-based-on-location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either search for a location OR search for a user, but you can definitely not search for "all users in an area". The Graph search on Facebook can handle a lot more things that you will never be able to get with the API. Think about privacy, i would not want any app to know if i am nearby, without even authorizing the App ;)

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

For getting the locatoin where the user is living, you need to check out the user reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

There is a "location" field in there, you need to authorize a user with the "user_location" permission to get that information. It is not possible to get that information from any user. Just because you can see data on Facebook and it is public does not mean you can access it with an App, for privacy reasons this is only possible by authorizing the user.

Scraping without an App is not allowed btw, check out the scraping terms: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: I'm not saying that I want to find every user by his current location. What I'm referring to is the information of where a person is living. And in most accounts this is set as public information, so it should be in principle available to everyone, including my app, without violating privacy of a person.

Comment: public does not mean you can access it for every user who did not authorize your app. that is not how it works with the api.

Comment: that being said, you cannot use the search api for getting the location where the user lives either. i will add some information about that in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I didn't knew there was such a strict distinction between a Facebook user and an app. But thanks for clarifying this. Seems, I have to come up with a completely different way to get the data.

Comment: there is really only one way to get the data: by authorizing the user with the user_location permission. everything else would be illegal, check out the scraping terms: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: i will add it to the answer, because it is important to know

Answer (score -1):

I tried this -> "firstname lastname location" and it works perfect. 
For example -> "Sameeksha kumari australia"

The query looks like this
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?fields=id,name,picture.type(normal),location&limit=500&q=sameeksha kumari melbourne&type=user&access_token=token