# Is it possible to get facebook users list by city location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well graph api has an oportunity to search users by location :

```
search?type=user&q=Tbilisi
```

It really gives me users list, but not much es excpected. It gives me only 400 users while in my city at least are more than 100 000 facebook users... Any idea, solution?

Comment: The result is paginated. You can access the next set of results using the link in the last element of the json object

Comment: I've done it and there are only 451 users

Comment: Probably there are only 451 users that matches the name *Tbilisi*

Comment: _“graph api has an oportunity to search users by location”_ – don’t know what gives you that idea – [as the documentation states](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search), with that query you are searching for users _by name_. You can not search for users by location via the API.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your main goal, here's another thread that answers your question:

> There is a "location" field in there, you need to authorize a user with the "user_location" permission to get that information

[How do I search Facebook for all users at a certain location using Graph-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830263/how-do-i-search-facebook-for-all-users-at-a-certain-location-using-graph-api)